# Imagebutton android tv

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv

After several attempts, I managed to work as a Imagebutton, android tv remote.
but add button is selected, or at least do not see a difference when selected.
I tried focus. but the button is not exactly still and see if it is selected or not.
what can i do ?
Thank you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ro.vrt.virtualespanatv.AndroidTv"
style="@style/Theme.Leanback.Browse"
android:background="@drawable/background">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView4" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false">
                </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/horizontalScrollView4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/horizontalScrollView4">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Categoria1"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tdt"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/Categoria2"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/adView"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    style="@android:style/MediaButton.Rew" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Categoria2"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tdt"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Categoria1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Categoria1"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is your ImageButton based upon a StateList with different values for focused, pressed, etc? See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you said

Answer (score 0):

Just add attribute `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to your `ImageView` to show an effect.